# Installed Hibernate Tools plugin for Eclipse but no access to code generation feature

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-tools

I'm using Eclipse Helios SR2 and I've just installed the Hibernate tools plugin (via the update site : http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/helios/). I now have the wizards to create the configuration file, mapping file and so on but something seems wrong : I don't have the "Hibernate code generation menu"?! Consequently, I'm not able to generate the domain classes based upon an existing database schema.

Can anyone explain what I am missing?

Comment: Just found it! Silly me, the "Hibernate code generation" menu appeared only when I am in the Hibernate perspective (which I actually never open when working on my project). Guess that the plugin itself could be improved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> the "Hibernate code generation" menu appeared only when I am in the Hibernate perspective

Not really, try with the following steps

- **Menu** -> Window -> Customize Perspective (current perspective)
- Command Groups Availability -> CHECKED the Hibernate Code Generation